# Running "ng new" within local Windows nodeJS install give npm error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I've extracted nodeJS to a local directory and I am attempting to run "ng new testproject" and I am getting the following error:

'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Please note that I CANNOT modify my local path (locked out by firm policy) so simply adding the directory to PATH does not work for me. How can I create and admin Angular  projects within my local node folder without modifying path?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7289) open issue seems relevant to that. A workaround seems to be running `npm install` manually.

Comment: Can you please answer my question with your comment so I can upvote you and mark it as correct answer? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to [this open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7289).

As per [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7289#issuecomment-320657417) a workaround is to run `npm install` manually after running `ng new`.